# How to refactor the code, to pass in accessible file path as input parameter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have this function that basically uploads a video to YouTube. However, currently I am having to hardcode the actual file path where the video is located(example: @"C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\audio\test.mp4";). I am wondering is there a way to make this more dynamic. For example have the user pass in the video, video name, and video description as an input parameter?

I am asking this because, I plan to move this function to Azure portal and there, I won't be able to specify local file path like I am doing right now.  Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.Threading;

namespace UploadVideoToYoutube
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            log.LogInformation("YouTube Data API: Upload Video");
            log.LogInformation("==============================");

            try
            {
                await Run();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    log.LogInformation("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
            return new OkObjectResult($"Video Processed..");
        }

        private static async Task Run()
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                    // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
            video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
            var filePath = var filePath = @"C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\audio\test.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

                await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
            }
        }

        private static void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
        {
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
                    break;

                case UploadStatus.Failed:
                    Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use http request with json file includes video info, the video should be sent as encoded `base64` string format, then decode in Azure Function and you may use dynamic path `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` to store before uploading youtube

Comment: @Tan Nguyen, sorry but I am not sure exactly what your are trying to suggest. Do you mind showing an example or show that part?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the items from the body

```
[FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] 
    HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    return name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

In your request, you can have a field containing the file bytes in a base 64 format.

#### warning

This is probably not the right way to do things. The files might get too big, the connections too flaky, etc.

I would suggest to try something like blob storage for the initial upload and if you need the description, when it's done invoke the function with the name of the file and a description.

If description is not so much of an issue, then maybe a blob trigger would suffice.

#### Blob storage trigger

You can find the official guide [on Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) on how to setup the project.

You can also check [accessing the blob with c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp). Mimimum example is shown below:

```
[FunctionName("BlobTriggerCSharp")]        
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}")] Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
}
```

Comment: yes blob storage is exactly what I was thinking.But I not familiar with how to integrate that within the code. Do you mind, showing how that can be done?

Comment: Check the updated answer. The topic is quite broad, so I added some links with extensive examples! Hope this helps.

Comment: so for example say I uploaded a new .mp4 file into my blob storage container. would that trigger this function then? If so, then I don’t need to mention the file path anymore in my current code correct?

Comment: That's exactly the case. The trigger will fire up when the file is uploaded and you can pick it up file and all. The only limitation of this is the description.

Comment: let me give this a try and will let you know should I have any questions. Thank you.

Comment: I am having  some issue with trying to refactor the code to make to convert it to blob trigger. Mainly, I am not sure how to handle the 'filepath' code:
var filePath = var filePath = @"C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\audio\test.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)){
                var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;